# How can I set up the Microsoft C compiler to make it prefer immediate-mode push instructions?

Tags: assembly, c, compilers, source-reconstruction

I started [a project](https://github.com/SzieberthAdam/hyperoid-rebuild/tree/master/rebuild#hyperoidalf) to get a better understanding on how to compile a game for Windows 3.x. I tried to set up the build workflow so that it produce the byte-exact clone of a great open sourced Win16 game named *[Hyperoid](https://www.freezenet.ca/review-hyperoid-windows-16-bit/)*. It took some time to get a working build for Windows 3.0 which I finally managed. However, no matter how I played with the compiler and linker options, I was not able to produce a similar EXE in some aspects.

One of them is related to stack handling. I see it in the disassembly that while the original EXE does `push CONSTANT` instructions, the rebuilt one usually put the constant to the AX register and does a `push ax`.

Original:

```
push 02FC
push 0000
push ds
```

New:

```
mov ax, 02FC
push ds
push ax
sub ax, ax
push ax
```

No matter how I played with the CL options, I was not able to change this behavior.

Is there a way to set up the Microsoft C 6.0 compiler to make it prefer constant push instructions over doing the same indirectly using registers?

(More details are in the project link above.)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`PUSH` immediate was introduced in the Intel 80186. The compiler needs to be configured to allow the usage of 186 opcodes with the `/G1` option, or any greater value such as `/G2` for 286 opcodes.

(These instructions were also implemented in NEC V20/V30 CPUs.)